# How to continue the chain?

Tags: c++, box2d

I use Box2d.

I create ChainShape.

Suddenly, I need to continue the chain.
I know command `SetNextVertex(b2Vec2(-2.0f, 0.0f));`

**How use it?  How to continue the chain?**

Comment: doesn't make sense to me

Comment: You will need to make another fixture and replace the original one.

Comment: iforce2d, well, then what helps SetNextVertex?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have created a Loop (The first and last vertices are connected).  As such the chain is complete.

If you did not want a loop you should have used CreateChain.

See 4.6 Chain Shapes in http://box2d.org/manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**The only current solution is as iforce2d mentions, to create a new fixture and replace the original one.**

Why?

As Andrew mentioned. "you have created a Loop (The first and last vertices are connected)".

What this means implementation wise: say you have three vertices, A:(0,0); B:(0,5); C:(5,0).
CreateLoop(vertices, 3) will be of length 4 not 3... index 0:A, 1:B, 2:C, and 3:A (notice A again). What SetNextVertex does it adds another vertex D:(1,1) to the back (i.e. braking the loop), 4:D. Unfortunately you cannot insert a vertex before the last index, thus maintaining the loop.

If you want to continue adding vertices to the loop, ask for a feature request :)